# Hyperlink variable - HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have a variable (ID) that I am trying to attach to a hyperlink.

```
<body>


<div id = "menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>          
        <li><a href="http://localhost/webpage8.php?ID='"+<?php echo $_GET['ID'] ?>+"'">C</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When running the code in a browser, the link for 'C' does open. However, the ID isn't attached to the end of it. It appears as such: http://localhost/webpage8.php?ID=27%
I am unsure as to what '%27' means as the ID is actually 'C001'

When using '$_GET['ID']' in webpage8.php, nothing is shown in the browser.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does the ID include the `'` character? Because `%27` - not `27%` - is the `urlencode`d version of `'`. Please post **your actual code**, and take a look at the resulting HTML in your browser's view-source.

Comment: Check your `$ID` variable value first. use `echo "ID value : ".$ID;`

Comment: Please take a look at the edited version.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you need to have all your variables inside the `<?php ?>`tags. Change your line of code with the URL to this.

```
<li><a href= "http://localhost/webpage8.php?ID=<?= urlencode($ID) ?>">C</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understand now what you said about PHP tags. However, your code isn't working for me.

Comment: Taken from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page. Basically what this means is that it will be able to handle all sorts of strings with special characters such as % & $ and convert them to their appropriate Unicode values.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the following a try

```
<?php
echo "<li><a href='http://localhost/webpage8.php?ID=";
echo $ID;
echo "'>C</a></li>";
?>
```

Your code doesn't work as you're trying to use a PHP variable in pure HTML.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: @NorthernStars, doesn't work _how_? Try adding `echo $_GET["ID"];` to webpage.php and see what'll happen

Comment: I have also tried this. It doesn't work because this is the URL when selecting the page: http://localhost:7777/actual/Staff_Children_Attendance_VIEW.php?ChildID=%27. What is mean by '%27'? The id is actually 'C001'.

Comment: It's a `'` sign. Have you examined the HTML generated by the `echo` call in the link? What does the link look like?